# save data in form in django

Tags: django, forms, post

I wanna save user_id and session value with form when form submit.

I have a model with Test name:

```
class Test(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     status = models.CharField()
```

and my form code is:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model = Test
          field = ('title',)
```

User just will see "title" input and when user submit the form just title will be save in db. But I wanna save user_id(via request.user) and status value(via session['status']) in DB too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it that way:

```
form = TestForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    test = form.save(commit=False)
    test.user = request.user
    test.status = 'some_status'
    test.save()
```